# Pass multiple parameters to ExpressJS error handler

Tags: node.js, express

I'd like to use the expressJS error handler to handle the errors in my app.

The problem is I'd like to attach a custom message to the error so I can customize what will be logged, and  keep the syntax lightweight :

```
if(err)
  return next(err, "Invalid user Id");
```

But I only see example in the documentation and on internet using only 1 error parameter.
The solution could be to pass an object but then the syntax wouldn't be lightweight any more :

```
if(err)
  return next({
    error   : err,
    message : "Invalid user Id"
  });
```

How can I do that with express ?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from your current solution you could do

```
if (err) {
    err.message += ": Invalid user id";
    return next(err);
}
```

or if you want to get rid of the original err object and just pass a new one

```
if (err) {
    return next(new Error("Invalid user id"));
}
```

Comment: I want to keep the original error and be able to handle it in one line

Comment: while I don't really see the point of doing it all on one line
`return next(err.message += ": Invalid user id"; err);`
However this reduces the readability quite a bit. You could extract out the operation into a separate function and give the illusion of a "oneliner" but that really doesn't seem necessary.
it's ok to have things on multiple lines. No really. it is.